# Bathroom shower wall tile is cracked across 4 tiles. Opinions?

Tags: bathroom, tile, moisture, replacement

Some structural guys bopped the back of a bathroom shower wall while installing some beams on the other side. A few subway tiles in a corner cracked in an area that get's a lot of moisture. Although I got a discount for the oops, it's been a while since I thought about this problem so there might be some moisture that has gotten in there already.

My question: if I have extra tile and grout for replacement, would ripping just these four tile (or maybe also the adjacent) out and replacing be a recommended thing to do, or would we have to replace all of the shower tub tile? I'm concerned about the corner placement, but maybe I shouldn't be (in the pic don't mind the blur on the tub, that was my quick and dirty photoshop fix to get rid of a hairball, only the four tile are affected)

Thanks for any feedback or suggestions

[image: TUB TILE, CRACKED, CORNER]

Comment: Ooof... I would have negotiated to have them pay for the fix instead of just a small discount.

Comment: Yeah, their liability insurance (or their desire not to make a claim on their liability insurance) should have paid for a proper repair - too late now, evidently.

Comment: Do you know what kind of waterproofing was used?

Answer (score 0):

The cracks themselves are just cosmetic and do not require remedial action, but the possibility of damage to whatever is under the tiles is another matter. A tiled surface  is not waterproof, and it is expected that moisture will reach whatever is behind. It is the "whatever" that must be able to resist moisture. If you do decide to replace the tiles, be aware that it is best practice to use an elastomeric material ("caulk") in the corners and tub interface rather than grout.